# Is there a way for nested constraint validation using Hibernate, without using @Valid annotation?

Tags: validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a huge object model with lots of nested objects and fields. I need to validate **all** fields of the base object. Is there a way to do that without adding `@Valid` annotation to all the fields?

Sample objects:

```
class A { @NotNull private String id; ...}
class B { @NotNull private String id; List<A> aList; ...}
class C { @NotNull private String id; B bInstance; A aInstance; ...}
class D { @NotNull private String id; List<C> cList; ... }
...
```

If I need to validate and instance of D recursively, I'll have to put `@Valid` in all the relevant fields in A, B, C, D. 
I have a large number of objects in my object model. It's easy to miss out on putting the annotation on a field.

Comment: Can't you create a custom validator that just validates only the base object?

Comment: @Bunti I need to validate the base object as well as all the nested objects recursively (and there are a lot); each nested object has a constraint to be validated.

Comment: Could you provide example code? Maybe the groups feature could help you, but you should provide some more information first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should add all the required `@Valid` annotations to your object graph.

If that's really going to be a problem, you could try to automate it using Hibernate Validator's API for dynamic constraint violation. You'd have to traverse your object model reflectively and call `valid()` for each reference (plain object reference or collections/maps/arrays) you encounter.

But I'd advice against it as it adds quite some complexity and makes the solution harder to understand than when looking at plain `@Valid`. annotations.

Comment: I have to add `@Valid` annotation to all the fields. Is there a way to ask Hibernate to validate assuming that all fields need to be validated recursively, without explicitly adding the annotation?

Comment: No, there isn't; You could only "automate" it using the API as I described.

Comment: I guess it is better to add the annotations.